# Scrolling divs, adjusting height and position automatically

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-animate, height, absolute

I need to scroll blocks of content in a div and I need equal space between each block but I can't really predict that the height of each block will be exactly the same, some might have four lines, some might have three. However the only way I got my scroller to work was to assign each block a specific height and position. Is there a way I can achieve the same result if the number of lines (and therefore height of the block) varies?

Here is my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phmhjna9/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="block block-1">1</div>
    <div class="block block-2">2</div>
    <div class="block block-3">3</div>
    <div class="block block-4">4</div>
    <div class="block block-5">5</div>
    <div class="block block-6">6</div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

CSS

```
.container
        {
            position: relative;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            width: 590px;
            height: 330px;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family: arial, sans;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align: center;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

.block 
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 90px;
            height: 90px;
            color: #fff;
        }

.block-1
        {
            background-color: #900;
        }

.block-2
        {
            top: 100px;
            background-color: #090;
        }

.block-3
        {
            top: 200px;
            background-color: #009;
        }

.block-4
        {
            top: 300px;
            background-color: #990;
        }

.block-5
        {
            top: 400px;
            background-color: #909;
        }

.block-6
        {
            top: 500px;
            background-color: #099;
        }
```

jQuery

```
$( "#prev" ).click(function() 
    {
        $( ".block" ).animate({ "top": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
    });

$( "#next" ).click(function()
    {
        $( ".block" ).animate({ "top": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need a way to check the height of the blocks to determine how far to scroll. Maybe the following could serve as some kind of inspiration:

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/phmhjna9/2/)

```
var currentBlock = 1,
    max = $('.container .block').length;

$( "#prev" ).click(function() {
    if(currentBlock > 1) {
        var previous = currentBlock-1;
        var h = $('.block-' + previous).height() + 5;
        $( ".block-1" ).animate({ "margin-top": "+=" + h + "px" }, "slow" );
        currentBlock--;
    }
});

$( "#next" ).click(function() {
    if(currentBlock < max) {
        var h = $('.block-' + currentBlock).height() + 5;
        $( '.block-1' ).animate({ "margin-top": "-=" + h + "px" }, "slow" );
        currentBlock++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving each block individually, try adding a wrapping container and moving that inside of your 'container' div. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/releaf/vydg85o7/1/

```js
$("#prev").click(function() {
  $(".scroll-body").animate({
    "top": "+=50px"
  }, "slow");
});

$("#next").click(function() {
  $(".scroll-body").animate({
    "top": "-=50px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  width: 590px;
  height: 330px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: arial, sans;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.scroll-body {
  position: absolute;
}
.block {
  width: 90px;
  min-height: 90px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.block-1 {
  background-color: #900;
}
.block-2 {
  background-color: #090;
}
.block-3 {
  background-color: #009;
}
.block-4 {
  background-color: #990;
}
.block-5 {
  background-color: #909;
}
.block-6 {
  background-color: #099;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll-body">
    <div class="block block-1">1</div>
    <div class="block block-2">2</div>
    <div class="block block-3">3</div>
    <div class="block block-4">4</div>
    <div class="block block-5">5</div>
    <div class="block block-6">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="prev">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```